# Matrix of a restriction of a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Given a symmetric matrix $M$ and its associated quadratic form $Q : \mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is there an obvious way to write down a matrix of the quadratic form $Q|_{U}$, the restriction of $Q$ to $U$ which is a subspace, for example a hyperplane, of the original space $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: How do you define $Q|_{U}$?

Comment: Write your matrix in a basis adapted to a decomposition $U\oplus W$, and then the matrix of $Q_{|U}$ is just the block matrix in $M$ correpsonding to $U$.

Comment: Define $N$ to be basis for $U$. Then the matrix of your restriction is simply $N^TMN$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B$ is a matrix whose columns form a basis for the subspace $U$, then
$$
A = B^\top MB
$$
is the matrix of the quadratic form relative to this basis. For an example and a detailed explanation of why this is the case, see [my post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4387198/81360).